# Akka actors not receiving Array[Byte]?

Tags: arrays, scala, concurrency, akka, actor

I am trying to write an actor that counts messages it receives and prints when it hits a specific number of messages seen.

I got it to work when I am sending the messages to the actor as a string, but when I try to send and Array[Bytes], the actor doesn't perform it's receive function, but it also doesn't invoke its catch else case.

Code for handling strings which works:

```
class CountingActor extends Actor {

  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  var count = 0
  val actorName = self.path.name

  def Count: Actor.Receive = {
    case message: String =>
      count += 1
      if(count % 50000 == 0 && count != 0){
        var elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis - startTime) / 1000.0
        var mps = count / elapsed
        log.info(s"Processed $count messages in $elapsed ($mps msg/s) in $actorName")
      }

    case _ => log.info("Something happened and I dont know, it wasn't a string")
  }

  def receive = Count

}
```

The code that fails to process and Array[Byte] is exactly the same but I specify the case as Array[Byte] instead of string.

```
class CountingActor extends Actor {

  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  var count = 0
  val actorName = self.path.name

  def Count: Actor.Receive = {
    case message: Array[Byte] =>
      count += 1
      if(count % 50000 == 0 && count != 0){
        var elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis - startTime) / 1000.0
        var mps = count / elapsed
        log.info(s"Processed $count messages in $elapsed ($mps msg/s) in $actorName")
      }

    case _ => log.info("Something happened and I dont know, it wasn't a string")
  }

  def receive = Count

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this scenario

```
  val s = ActorSystem()
  val ca = s.actorOf(Props[CountingActor])
  ca ! Array[Byte](1, 1, 0)
```

and it works just fine. Try to add additional logging after

```
case message: Array[Byte] =>
```

to see this. Now your code doesn't show any visible reaction on this message if `count` is less than 50000, so how do you know that "the actor doesn't perform it's receive function"?

Comment: I'll try it again. I'm just assuming it wasn't since I threw 100,000 messages at it and saw no prints, but thanks, I will re-evaluate the counting logic.